# Vulkan clear color is wrong

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am following https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction to get myself familiar with the Vulkan API. I have gotten to the point where my application is able to draw a triangle. But for some reason the clear color is way brighter than the RGB value that i specified in my code. I am setting the color like this:

```
    VkClearValue clearColor = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo = {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO,
        .renderPass = renderPass,
        .framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[i],
        .renderArea = {
            .offset = {
                .x = 0,
                .y = 0
            },
            .extent = swapChainExtent
        },
        .clearValueCount = 1,
        .pClearValues = &clearColor
    };
```

An RGB value of [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0] or [50, 50, 50, 255] should be a very dark gray, almost black. Instead i am getting is this:

[image]

This looks more like an RGB value of [150,150,150,255]. To get a color close to what i want i have to instead go with something like this:

```
VkClearValue clearColor = {0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f, 1.0f};
```

So it almost seems like everything is shifted by a decimal. Any idea what might cause this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the VkFormat being selected for the VkSurfaceFormat, most likekly VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB. Try VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM for the VkFormat with a corresponding colorspace (like VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR). That should give the dark color you are expecting.